# Flutter merge search queries?

Tags: flutter, dart, repository

We have a Laravel + Flutter based platform.

When a search query is returned in our Flutter application, it prints the products on the screen by making an API call as follows.
api/foods?search=EXAMPLE;&searchFields=name:like;&limit:70;
Our search is sorted by name.

When I search for "EXAMPLE", I want a listing based on the name, followed by products with "EXAMPLE" in the description. So this query;
api/foods?search=EXAMPLE;&searchFields=description:like;&limit:70;

I mean, having these two queries done one after the other; How can I list it in the search results so that it lists the name first and then the description?

yani EXAMPLE aramasının sonucunda
önce "api/foods?search=EXAMPLE;&searchFields=name:like;&limit:70;" sorgusu,
altında da birleşik bir şekilde "api/foods?search=EXAMPLE;&searchFields=description:like;&limit:70;" sorgusunun yer almasını istiyorum.

Flutter Codes;

```
Future<Stream<Food>> searchFoods(String search) async {
  Uri uri = Helper.getUri('api/foods');
  Map<String, dynamic> _queryParams = {};
  _queryParams['search'] = '$search';
  _queryParams['searchFields'] = 'name:like;';
  _queryParams['limit'] = '70';
  uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: _queryParams);
  try {
    final client = new http.Client();
    final streamedRest = await client.send(http.Request('get', uri));

    return streamedRest.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder).map((data) => Helper.getData(data)).expand((data) => (data as List)).map((data) {
      return Food.fromJSON(data);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: uri.toString()).toString());
    return new Stream.value(new Food.fromJSON({}));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have 2 ListViews in the Column so that you can display results from 2 lists. The other option is to merge the list into one and then send it to your UI to display in single ListView.

Comment: Can you share sample code? I'm trying to learn dart language better and I can't figure it out.. :/

Comment: Sure. 

Column(
  children: [
    ListView(), // for displaying based on name
    ListView(), // for displaying based on description
   ],
),